# compressing single sentence with python and stanford NLP

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to create a sentence from a given sentence. I mean if I am given with a following sentence:

```
I will go home and come back tomorrow.
```

So the output should be a compressed sentence having semantically meaning like:

```
Tomorrow, I will come back
```

Now I tried many paraphraser and sentence reconstructors or rewriter using python2 and also python3.

For example I have used the Takahe repository for paraphrasing: https://github.com/boudinfl/takahe based on multi - line paraphrasing using the research paper:  http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/N13-1030

but this is not what I am trying to achieve. I am looking for a single sentence to sentence generation technique.

So I thought to use stanford library and python. But I am not getting any clue for the start. Even I have tried something but that is a comparing similarity or syntactically. The code is here on my gist:   https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/2c5cf8232369a972862a9079923cb740

Kindly, help me to resolve my issue and confusion. I hope to hear a cooncrete solution that will help me successfully run a semantic based sentence creator/ generator.

Comment: What do you mean by "having semantically meaning"? You want to have input and output sentence to have the same meaning? Because your example sentences *don't* have the same meaning; in the second one, some information is missing (it's unknown where the speaker is coming back from).

Comment: @lenz Yes you are correct. May be my example needs a renewal. I need to compress the sentence with same meaning. That is the purpose. I just showed you that the output must be in lesser words as compared to the input sentence words.

Comment: @lenz you got my point, my friend? do you have any solution for this?

Comment: No, haven't quite got your point. Do you have sentences that have a lot of redundancy? Because otherwise it's very hard or even impossible to say the same thing with fewer words – *for a human*. Try it yourself: pick any of the sentences of your post or this conversation and try to shorten it without losing information. For doing this automatically, you will have to lower your expectations much more. AFAIK there is no tool that can reliably tell if two given sentences have the same meaning.

Comment: My intuition would be to have a look at neural seq2seq (encoder-decoder) approaches. This could be used to train a model to translate long sentences to shorter sentences. There are quite a few examples on the web, e.g. https://github.com/llSourcell/How_to_make_a_text_summarizer

Comment: Actually, I have gone through these seq2seq model. They are not upto the mark. I have used Gigawords and Tesla K80 (16 GPUs) for training and got absolutely no proper answer. I kept on training for 2 months consistently on the AWS instance.

Comment: Is there any way to make the single sentence shorter. That would help too. Not the abstractive output but let's consider extractive in shorter words.

Comment: ok... lets make it easier to understand. Is there a way to change sentence structure without changing meaning of it using the Stanford NLP or python nltk or anything. I hope this make sense.

Comment: I don't think so. Such an approach would be very brittle, costly to make, hard to maintain, and probably it would still change the meaning in many cases or even produce meaningless output.